# Same short encryption result using AES with different keys

Tags: c, openssl, aes

I have a single plain text which is

`unsigned char plaintext[] = "Hi, this is trial number one";`

For the keys, instead of using something like:

`unsigned char key[16] = "azertyuiopqsdfg";`

I decided to use tons of them like `"dog", "azkier", "jfieifdragon", ...`

My code so far looks like this:

```
unsigned char *aes_encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, unsigned char *key)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    unsigned char iv[16] = "0000000000000000";

    int c_len = strlen(plaintext) + AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    int f_len = 0;
    unsigned char *ciphertext = malloc(c_len);

    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &c_len, plaintext, strlen(plaintext));

    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext+c_len, &f_len);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext;
}
```

When I compile and run, the output looks something like this:

```
the key: dog
the plain: Hi, this is trial number one
ciphertext: 157a320

the key: azkier
the plain: Hi, this is trial number one
ciphertext: 157a320

.....
```

My questions are:

why I always get the same ciphertext even though I'm using different keys?

Also, why the ciphertext is really short? My plaintext is pretty long tho.

Thanks.

Update --> The way I call the aes_encrypt is like this:

```
unsigned char plaintext[] = "Hi, this is trial number one";
unsigned char *cipher;
cipher = aes_encrypt(plaintext, "dog");
printf("The cipher is: %x\n", cipher);
free(cipher);

unsigned char *cipher;
cipher = aes_encrypt(plaintext, "azkier");
printf("The cipher is: %x\n", cipher);
free(cipher);
```

Comment: Please include the code that you're using to test your function.

Comment: @duskwuff do you mean my main()?

Comment: Possibly! Whatever code is calling `aes_encrypt` and printing output.

Comment: @duskwuff updated.

Comment: @Chris The code compiles already, they are just showing the wrong output. cipherT is a typo.

Comment: I mean include enough code that someone could just copy, paste and compile. With the `#include` and `int main()` and all that. And it shouldn't compile if you have a typo anyway.

Comment: I don't see much immediately wrong. Try some debugging stuff: stick some `printf`s in your function and make sure everything is sane. You also should test the return values of the `EVP` calls to check for errors there.

Comment: One issue: it's important that your key is the right length. Should cut the key off at 16 bytes or pad it to 16 bytes if it's the wrong length.

Comment: @Chris yeah I did that. all the keys are guaranteed 16 bytes or below.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I was under the impression it had to be exactly 16 bytes...

Comment: CBC mode provides confidentiality only, and you usually must add a MAC to use CBC mode safely. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww I going to read this first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test code:

```
printf("The cipher is: %x\n", cipher);
```

Well, of course that doesn't work -- `%x` prints the *address* of `cipher` as hexadecimal, not its contents. If you want a dump of the contents of `cipher`, you'll need to loop over each byte yourself.

Additionally, the `key` parameter to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` is a fixed-length buffer, whose size is set based on the cipher you're using. **It is not a string.** Passing a short string may cause unpredictable behavior, as whatever data happens to be stored after the string ends may be used as part of the key.

Comment: I got "ciphertext: 157a320". So what are those random digits?

Comment: The address of `cipher`.

Comment: @duskwuff you are right. I tried for loop and it started to show different value. However, how do I know the proper length of the cipher? should I used `i < sizeof(ciphertext)`?

Comment: Call `EVP_CIPHER_key_length`. Or look it up -- there's only one value for any given cipher.

Comment: @duskwuff can you provide an example to what you just said about `EVP_EncryptInit_ex`. I saw the manual page and they can used something like `unsigned char key[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};`. So should I do something like: `unsigned char key[] = {"dog", "blalal", "sdfas"};` ?

Comment: @duskwuff do I need to pad the string or hex the string first then?